# extracting rows by comparing keys keys

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have two `pandas` dataframes as:

```
df1.ix[1:5]

     Keys   ColName
1    LOSTP  LOSTP1
2    LOSTP  LOSTP2
3    LOSTP  LOSTP3
4    GIDEO  GIDEOasdun
5    sdfff  sdfffvrf


df2.ix[1:5]

     Keys   ColName
2    LOSTQ  LOSTQ2
3    LOSTR  LOSTR3
5    sdfff  sdfffvrf
```

I want to extract the following from `df1`:

```
     Keys   ColName
1    LOSTP  LOSTP1
2    LOSTP  LOSTP2
3    LOSTP  LOSTP3
4    GIDEO  GIDEOasdun
```

which implies `df1['keys] difference df2['keys']`. i.e. find elements from df1 which are not in df2 by comparing them on `keys` column

Answer (score 0):

```
#use an apply function to see if the colname in the current row is in df2 colnames with the same key as the current row. Then use this mask array to select rows.

df1[df1.apply(lambda x: x.ColName not in df2[df2.Keys==x.Keys]['ColName'].tolist(), axis=1)]
Out[272]: 
    Keys     ColName
1  LOSTP      LOSTP1
2  LOSTP      LOSTP2
3  LOSTP      LOSTP3
4  GIDEO  GIDEOasdun
```